# How to only allow vanilla/Optifine players to join a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

There are people that join my Minecraft server with Fabric/Forge loaders, any possible way to block them from joining the server if they're using anything other than Vanilla/Optifine?

Comment: Why don't you want Fabric/Forge players being in your server? I am pretty sure Fabric/Forge shouldn't negatively affect your server just because it's being launched from those. If anything you would be limiting your server to fewer people (assuming it's not already a private server). Then again I'm not exactly experienced with alternate Minecraft launchers, as I use the vanilla one. Regardless i'm pretty sure it shouldn't affect you too much.

Comment: Forge/Fabric mods can give you a huge fps boost, there's some packs that are multiple times better than optifine. There's also QoL mods like mousetweaks and controlling that don't really give an unfair advantage.

Anyways, the only way you can 100% do what you were thinking (and the best way) is to talk to the people joining and agree what is and isn't allowed.

There are plugins that can do this, but nothing is stopping players from downloading a mod that will make their client lie to your server about what mods they are using, and tbh I wouldn't blame them

Comment: Realistically, you can't stop people from using them. It is a simple matter to install a mod that spoofs your client to be vanilla. It is better to let people using forge and fabric to join, since you at least know who is using them. Additionally, this would just be inconvenient for people using legit mods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a player is using Fabric or Forge when they try to join your Minecraft server, you can use a plugin to do this. There are several plugins available that can check the mods a player is using and block them from joining if they are using certain mods.

To use a plugin to block players using Fabric or Forge, you will first need to install a plugin management system on your Minecraft server. The most commonly used plugin management system is called Bukkit, but there are also other options available such as Spigot and Paper.

Once you have installed a plugin management system, you can search for a plugin that will check for players using Fabric or Forge and block them from joining the server. Some popular plugins for this purpose include ModControl, AntiForge, and ModBlocker.